# C# Combo Box items number multiplication

Tags: c#, combobox, windows-forms-designer

I copy manually form excel to string collection (ComboBox) 2 columns, 1 is account (456939493) number the second is the percent(0.001) in decimals.

```
this.percent.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
        "456939493 0.001 ",
        "453949343 0.00001",
```

operation

```
double Pairdecimal = Convert.ToDouble(percent.SelectedValue);
```

When the multiplication operation is executed it does not read the decimals, and only generated the number zero.

What can do to get only the decimal and not the account number from the string collection (ComboBox).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers!
I took both suggestions/answers and made it work for my code.

```
string[] str = currpair.Text.Split(); //from Ric Gaudet
```

Then I also took

```
double secondValue = Convert.ToDouble(str[1]); //from swistak
```

Thanks again my problem is solved.
Now I can multiply the comboBox value.

Answer (score 1):

You can split string and then convert first part to int. Like this:

```
var splitStrings = percent.SelectedValue.Split();
var firstValue = Convert.ToInt32(splitStrings[0]); //int
var secondValue = Convert.ToDouble(splitStrings[1]); //double
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, and swistak has provided one good answer.
You need to separate the string into its component parts first, and then convert the desired part to a double (or decimal).

```
        string text = "456939493 0.001 ";

        //one option
        string[] textArray = text.Split(' ');
        double num1 = Convert.ToDouble( textArray[1]);

        //another option
        double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(text.Substring(10));  
       // this assumes the account number is always the same length
```